# phpMyAdmin access has suddenly become very slow

Tags: phpmyadmin

I used to be able to access and export database from phpmyadmin fine but it has suddenly become very very slow and trying to export a 20 mb data results in Network Failure Error. I had created another instance using the same server a month ago and I can access that just fine.
The only changes in the past few days are enabling logging and adding a cron job in cron.daily to back up the database.

I have tried restarting the instance and also cleared browser cache. Tried using two different computers.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a shared hosting environment? Is it possible the machine is under heavy load due to other factors? Have you tried enabling the [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) to look for slow queries? From the phpMyAdmin main page, there's a Status tab which contains some means you can look throiugh; for instance the process list might help identify long-running processes. Have you tried disabling the logging? Check to see whether your cron job got hung up in some way (for instance, `ps` on the command line). Again at the command-line, check your system load (perhaps with `top`).